# SQL - Select record from table 1 if exists otherwise select "matching" record from table 2

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I am trying to do is write a query that selects all regions for an employee.
There are two region tables: `employee_region` & `department_region`.
The employee region is based on an employees id `(employee.id = employee_region.id)` & takes precedence over the `employee_region` table.
However, if there are any missing records based on a region then we should default to the `department_region` table for those values.

I want 2 records returned that include the values **SOUTHWEST 8745829483** & **NORTHWEST 3125533132**. Notice the value for **SOUTHWEST** comes from the `employee_region` table because this table takes precedence over the `department_region` while **NORTHWEST** only exists in the `department_region` table.

EMPLOYEE

| ID | DEPT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 4a059d6a-b086-462b-a5b4-49a725a16c60 |

EMPLOYEE_REGION

| ID | REGION | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | SOUTHWEST | 8745829483 |

DEPARTMENT

| ID | NAME | PHONE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4a059d6a-b086-462b-a5b4-49a725a16c60 | SALES | 673-348-2928 |

DEPARTMENT_REGION

| ID | REGION | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4a059d6a-b086-462b-a5b4-49a725a16c60 | SOUTHWEST | 1111111111 |
| 4a059d6a-b086-462b-a5b4-49a725a16c60 | NORTHWEST | 3125533132 |

Comment: I'm not at a computer at the moment and also mainly use Oracle rather than Postgres  but I think this would be straightforward with a couple of left outer joins so that employee, employee_region and department_region are all pulled together with possible null values in the columns from employee_region, then use nvl (or coalesce or case when) in your select statement to get employee_region values if not null, else department_region. Hope that gives you a pointer

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: @lemon I figured it out but, thank you. Do you happen to know how I could use COALESCE for the entire record instead of having to use it per column data type. I'd prefer to use something like this COALESCE(er.*, dr.*) if possible so it reduces the individual select values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(er.region, dr.region), COALESCE(er.score, dr.score) 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON (d.ID = e.DEPT_ID)
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT_REGION dr ON (d.ID = dr.ID)
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_REGION er ON (er.ID = e.ID AND er.REGION = dr.REGION);
```